# Android APP not showing in "data" directory

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy, android-package-managers, internal-storage

I have created an Android APP using Titanium (Alloy). In the APP I am trying to store files locally in the **applicationDataDirectory**

When I try a

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(.....)
if(file.exists())
   alert('You found me !');
```

I do get an alert with the message.

Although, I can't seem to find the file anywhere in my internal storage. I am using a MotoG (4.4.4)

Note: I am running the application on my phone via

```
ti build -p android -T devices
```

I have looked in

```
/data
/Android/data
```

I don't even find my < packagename > anywhere. Any thoughts ?

Comment: apk: `/system/app`
app: `/data/data/package/`

Comment: Newer Android versions (with multi-user support) come up with different and personalized file path schemes to keep private app data separate from each other. You could try and `alert` the file name: `alert(file);` to see where the file is hiding.

Comment: @user2713030 I installed via the APK, but I do not know where the /system folder exists. It not in my mounted devices (unless hidden)

Comment: @NobuGames yes the path splits out file:///data/data/< package >/app_appdata/files/110f5b2951a72728c4d2054803a0365b but I have no idea where that is !

Comment: These files are not normally going to be visible (other than by the app itself) unless your device is rooted (such as the emulator is).

Comment: @PrakashRaman please share your answer